# Strange hyperlink handling in Excell, clicking on links always prompts for sign in even when it shouldn't

Tags: excel, ms-office

From my enterprise application, I can export a list of assets into an Excel file or a PDF file which puts a clickable hyperlink that points to the asset. When I open the hyperlink in the browser by clicking on the hyperlink in the excel file, my application prompts me to sign in (which it shouldn't).

This doesn't happen when I click on the hyperlink in the PDF file or manually copy the hyperlink and paste it into the browser window. When I save this excel file as a PDF and then click on the hyperlinks then it works as expected(without re-prompt for sign in). I have also manually created hyperlinks both using the formula(=HYPERLINK) and using the Link context menu and the behaviour is the same in these two cases (Prompted for signing). I have also tried this with word and it's also prompting for me to sign in.

Is Excell/MS Office doing anything additional whenever I click on these hyperlinks and if so how can I disable this functionality? How are external URL's handled in the MS office?

My document would look something like below(with a lot more columns)

[image]

Comment: sign in what? office 356 acc or other?

Comment: sign in to my enterprise application to view the asset. Generally, it should directly open when there is an active session in the browser.

Comment: then there is no problem with excel.. just highlight to ur IT admin on the issue to grant the bypass. | It is a standard security practice to block/control automated link opening in enterprise asset/network. | No offense there, just business. | afaik, ur app are working fine.

Comment: I have already checked with the IT. When I click on the link after saving the excel file as PDF then the link opens as expected(without asking for a sign-in in the browser). The behaviour is the same with MS word. The link is not completely blocked when I click on the link it still opens in the browser but takes me to sign in instead of taking to the asset page. MS office might be doing some wrapping or opening this in some special way may be for security or to restrict access which I am not sure what's happening.

Comment: the wrap is there... yes agreed. sort of link office "Generally, it should directly open when there is an active session in the browser." <-- does it opens normally if there is NO active session? d u get the same login page?

Comment: Yes, when there is no active session then I get the same login page that is expected. This also happens to the links in the PDF file(Expected).  I really appreciate you taking the time to look into this. Thank you

the wrap is there... <-- is there any option to disable this?

Comment: tty openoffice (alternative spreadsheet with compatible cell formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when a hyperlink is opened in any word document MS office process it and if it needs to be opened in a browser it opens with a new session ignoring the session id. Some SSO providers do not recognise authentications across sessions and hence prompt for authentication again. This can be avoided by instructing the MS office to open the URLs directly in the browser by modifying the registry key.

Create a new `DWORD` named `ForceShellExecute` and set its value to `1` in the below registry entries (Most probably the registry key will not be present, create a new one)

For 32-bit versions of Office installed on 64-bit operating systems:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet`

For 32-bit versions of Office installed on 32-bit operating systems, or 64-bit versions of Office installed on 64-bit operating systems:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet`

`Note:` Even though I have 64bit Office 365 enterprise I had to set the 32bit registry key.

Links to Microsoft KB articles: [Issue explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/click-hyperlink-to-sso-website) and [Solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-locate-server-when-click-hyperlink)